# сортировка строк по алфавиту с константными строками

Tags: c#

в тхт есть строки типа:

```
o82hg
|iu
|19
|93
ikueghw
|98
|jг
|as
```

мне нужно чтобы софт отсортировал строки которые находятся после "|" знака, чтобы он были в алфавитном поряде, но после сортировки будет начало такое

```
o82hg
ikueghw
|as
|iu
|jr
|19
|93
|98
```

***после правильной сортировки должно быть так:***

```
o82hg
|iu
|19
|93
ikueghw
|as
|jr
|98
```

то есть софт будет все целиком сортировать, а надо чтобы он игнорировал строки, которые не начинаются с "|" знака, то есть они так и останутся на свои местах, а отсортируется только то что с  таким "|" знаком... 
еще инфа....
"монтироватся" должны в интервале между строк, которые НЕ начинаются с палки, то есть если есть, допустим, 15 строк с палкой, то они там же и останется, только будет смонтирован....но строки без палок, останутся там же где и были

код, который мне был дан на форуме данном....

```
class Line
    {
        public string Text
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Fragment
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
    private string getFragment(string s, string digits)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return string.Empty;

        var t = s.Split('|');
        if (t.Count() == 1)
            return string.Empty;
        s = t[t.Count() - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; i++)
        {
            s = s.Replace(digits[i], (char)i);
        }
        return s;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string digits = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        var list = new List<Line>();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\text.txt");
        foreach (var s in lines)
        {
            list.Add(new Line { Text = s, Fragment = getFragment(s, digits) });
        }
        lines = list.OrderBy(r => r.Fragment, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\text.txt", lines);
    }
```

Comment: А что не так с этим кодом?

Comment: @VladD он сортирует все строки целиком во всем файле..

Comment: Напиши свой компаратор

Comment: @Alex78191 а по-русски ?

Comment: Ну так у вас строки должны сортироваться в пределах строк без палок или в пределах всего файла?

Comment: @Alex78191 "монтироватся" должны в интервале между строк, которые НЕ начинаются с палки, то есть если есть, допустим, 15 строк с палкой, то они там же и останется, только будет смонтирован....но строки без палок, останутся там же где и были..

Comment: @Tode вообще-то сортироваться

Comment: @Alex78191 вообще-то вы смысл поняли...

Comment: @Tode почему эту важную информацию вы не указали в вопросе?

Comment: @Alex78191 указал **над** строкой "код, который мне был дан на форуме данном..."

Comment: Написано непонятно, ок

Comment: Не легче ли в JSON, XML или бинарно сериализовывать? А не изобретать собственный формат хранения с палками.

Comment: @Alex78191 а что много ли кода надо редактировать ?

Comment: @Tode возможно вам вообще не нужно эту проблему решать, вы сами задаете формат хранения данных?

Comment: А покажите, какое содержимое должно быть у файла после сортировки?

Comment: @Alex78191 понимаете....мне нужно отсортировать все строки, которые начинаются с палки, но не переварачивать весь тхт, больше ниче не надо!

Comment: Так я же уже привел пример как должно быть после сортировки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуемся одной из перегрузок метода [`Array.Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/14at654h(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] lines =
    {
        "o82hg",
        "|iu",
        "|ev",
        "|bq",
        "|93",
        "ikueghw",
        "|98",
        "|jг",
        "|as",
        "jhgdsdg",
        "|iy",
        "|qn",
        "|pl",
        "|dl",
        "|rm",
        "5vsdvs",
        "|lf",
        "|8f",
        "|8b",
        "|8q",
        "|bt",
    };

    var indexess = lines.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
                        .Where(a => !a.s.StartsWith("|"))
                        .Select(a => a.i)
                        .Union(new[] { lines.Length })
                        .ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < indexess.Length - 1; ++i)
        Array.Sort(lines, indexess[i] + 1, indexess[i + 1] - indexess[i] - 1);

    Array.ForEach(lines, Console.WriteLine);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Вывод:

```
o82hg
|93
|bq
|ev
|iu
ikueghw
|98
|as
|jг
jhgdsdg
|dl
|iy
|pl
|qn
|rm
5vsdvs
|8b
|8f
|8q
|bt
|lf
```

---

Для того, чтобы при сортировке буквы стояли раньше цифр, нужно использовать сторонний `Comparer`, я взял его из [ответа @tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/686909/218063) и немного модифицировал:

```
class MyStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.Length && i < y.Length; i++)
        {
            var result = Compare(x[i], y[i]);
            if (result != 0) return result;
        }
        return string.Compare(x, y);
    }

    private int Compare(char x, char y)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(x) && char.IsLetter(y)) return 1;
        if (char.IsLetter(x) && char.IsDigit(y)) return -1;
        return Comparer<char>.Default.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

Теперь просто создайте экземпляр этого класса и передайте его в метод `Array.Sort()`:

```
var comparer = new MyStringComparer();

for (int i = 0; i < indexess.Length - 1; ++i)
    Array.Sort(lines, indexess[i] + 1, indexess[i + 1] - indexess[i] - 1, comparer);
```

Вывод:

```
o82hg
|bq
|ev
|iu
|93
ikueghw
|as
|jг
|98
jhgdsdg
|dl
|iy
|pl
|qn
|rm
5vsdvs
|bt
|lf
|8b
|8f
|8q
```

Comment: надо чтобы буквы шли с начало  потом цифры, и будет файл а не  `string[] lines =
    {`

Comment: Компаратор возьмите из одного из других ответов и передайте его в метод `Sort`  Ну а с файлом - `File.ReadAllLines()`. Основной посыл этого ответа - это показать как воспользоваться одной из подходящих перегрузок `Array.Sort()`, которая сортирует часть массива

Comment: И все-таки, можете редактировать ответ, т.к. нужнее с начало буквы а потом уже цифры...

Comment: @Tode, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Наклепал наивную реализацию. Основная сортировка выглядит так

```
string[] Sort (string[] input)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    var current = new List<string>();
    var comparer = new CustomComparer();

    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        if (item.StartsWith("|"))
        {
            current.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {           
            result.AddRange(current.OrderBy(x=>x, comparer));
            result.Add(item);
            current.Clear();
        }
    }

    result.AddRange(current.OrderBy(x=>x, comparer));
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Накатал свой компарер с блекджеком. Он нужен только чтобы выставить буквы при сортировке раньше чисел. Если вам это не важно, просто уберите компарер из кода.

```
class CustomComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var min = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);
        for (var i = 0; i < min; i++)
        {
            var result = Compare(x[i], y[i]);
            if (result!=0) return result;
        }

        return string.Compare(x, y);
    }

    private int Compare(char x, char y)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(x) && !char.IsDigit(y)) return 1;
        if (!char.IsDigit(x) && char.IsDigit(y)) return -1;
        return Comparer<char>.Default.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

Проверил вот так

```
void Main()
{
    var sampleData = new[] {
        "o82hg",
        "|iu",
        "|19",
        "|93",
        "ikueghw",
        "|98",
        "|jг",
        "|as",
    };    

    foreach(var item in Sort(sampleData))
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Получил в консоли вывод

```
o82hg
|iu
|19
|93
ikueghw
|as
|jг
|98
```

Answer (score 1):

После сортировки элементы в массиве `lines` будут в следующем порядке. Числа при сортировке с помощью стандартного компаратора идут в начале.

```
o82hg
|19
|93
|iu    
ikueghw
|98
|as
|jr
```

`CustomStringComparer` нельзя использовать для решения вопроса при сортировке с помощью `OrderBy`.

```
string file = @"o82hg
|iu
|19
|93
ikueghw
|98
|jг
|as";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(file, "\r?\n");
Array.Sort(lines, new CustomStringComparer(StringComparer.CurrentCulture));

class CustomStringComparer : IComparer<string>
        {
            private readonly IComparer<string> _baseComparer;

            public CustomStringComparer(IComparer<string> baseComparer)
            {
                _baseComparer = baseComparer;
            }

            public int Compare(string x, string y)
            {
                if ((!y.Contains("|")) || (!x.Contains("|")))
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                return _baseComparer.Compare(x, y);
            }
        }
```